# revolution slider doesn't appear on my homepage

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm using wordpress "The 7 theme" with a revolution slider on it , It was working great but suddenly now it's not 
and the only thing that appears is "The LOADING spinner "
any solutions .. ?
I deleted it and made a new one , this was the result[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Knvu.png)

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for that but my bet is that the slider is broken because you manually put some html/css in one of the layers and you forget to close the div tag or something like that. Or maybe there is some javascript conflict with some other plugin. It is hard to tell if you don't give some more information about how you are using the slider

Comment: Thank you for your reply Goran .. I didn't use any html or css , I made the slides and took the short code to my home page , and it was working but  suddenly now it's not , and as i said  the only thing that appears is "The loading spinner "

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED .. I deleted the whole slide and made a new one , and it appeared on my homepage with this message under it(Revolution Slider Error : Slider with alias none not found .. Maybe you mean acc_homepage ) so I went to alias and rename it to "none" .. and went to home page and deleted the slide with the name acc_homepage .. THANKS #Goran you inspired me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED .. I deleted the whole slide and made a new one , and it appeared on my homepage but[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PatD0.png) with this message under it(Revolution Slider Error : Slider with alias none not found .. Maybe you mean acc_homepage ) so I went to alias and rename it to "none" .. and went to home page and deleted the slide with the name acc_homepage .. THANKS #Goran you inspired me .